# Better Way To Write To A File?

Tags: python, file

Goal:

I have a file named `airplanes.txt`. It already contains some of my favourite planes:

```
Boeing 747
Airbus A380
```

I am taking an input in my main app in order to add a plane stated by the user into this `airplanes.txt` file.

Example:
`Please type the name of the plane you want to add to your favourites list:`  <<Boeing 737>>

If you look at the `airplanes.txt` file now you see:

```
Boeing 747
Airbus A380
Boeing 737
```

My question:
My code below works by first getting the existing data in the `airplanes.txt`.

```
airplane_file = open('airplanes.txt', 'r')

favourite_airplanes = [ line.strip('\n') for line in airplane_file.readlines()]

airplane_file.close()
```

Next, I close the file, and then, take a user input.

```
add_plane = input('Enter The Airplane You Would Like To Add To This List: ')
```

Finally, I write back all the existing data which was in the file and then add on the user input to that.

```
if add_plane != None:
    reopened_airplane_file = open('airplanes.txt', 'r+')
    for airplane in favourite_airplanes:
        reopened_airplane_file.write(f'{airplane}\n')
    else:
        reopened_airplane_file.write(f'{add_plane}\n')
```

I feel like there should be some way to write data into existing files which contain data without needing to rewrite all the data back into it + new data.

This can become increasingly tedious as, for enormous files, it would take a huge amount to time to write only the existing data back into the file and then write the new data which you would expect to add.

I have tried to make this question as readable as possible by deconstructing my code so I hope you don't mind the long question. `:)`

Edit:

This worked for me:

```
with open('airplanes.txt', 'a+') as file:
    add_plane = input('Enter The Airplane You Would Like To Add To This List: ')
    file.write(f'{add_plane}\n')
```

Why it wasn't working:
I was using the `r+` mode which meant that I was overwriting though `a+` mode was the appropriate one to use!
`a+` open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist.

Comment: Ever heard of append?

Comment: No, though is it as simple as just calling write() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open files in different modes, that is read them, write to them or append to them. This is done via the second parameter "r", "w", "a", optionally with "+" or "b" for "byte mode". Additionally, use `with open(...)` instead.
That said, you might use:

```
with open("test.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write("\nBoeing 737")
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this and it doesn't work, it deletes some of my existing data

Comment: @TheBossProSniper: Please be more precise on "doesn't work".

Comment: I edited my question, and now it seems that the data is being overwritten

Comment: Hey its still getting overwritten

Comment: I am trying what you are suggesting however, for some awkward reason, it is overwriting to my file

Comment: Could you explain what the a+ stands for? I want to understand what caused the faliure to write properly

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write/append to the file at the same time, so here is how it's gonna work in your case:

```
with open('airplanes.txt', 'a+') as airplane_file:
    
    favourite_airplanes = [line.strip('\n') for line in airplane_file.readlines()]
    
    add_plane = input('Enter The Airplane You Would Like To Add To This List: ')
    
    if add_plane != None:
        airplane_file.write(f'{add_plane}\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("airplanes.txt", "a+") as ap_txt:
    add_plane = input('Enter The Airplane You Would Like To Add To This List: ')
    ap_txt.write("\n{}".format(add_plane))
```

Comment: Thanks for a clean and succinct answer, I spent a lot of time writing this question :) I would appreciate it if you could upvote, not many beginners know about the a+ tag and think that the w+ or r+ tag would do the trick

Comment: The complete answer is nice. Emphasis on a+ with some explanation would improve a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('airplanes.txt', 'a+') as f:

 fav_air = f.readlines()

planes_list = [i.strip() for i in fav_air] 

add_plane = input('Enter The Airplane You Would Like To Add To This List: ') 

for plane in planes_list:

      if add_plane != plane:

             f.write("\n")
        
            # Append text at the end of file
        
             f.write(plane)
     
      else:

            print(" Airplane already in the list")
```